# Why is my my controller not showing all the text fields properly?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield, rubymotion

I've got two controllers. On first controller I have an add button. clicking this presents the user with a second controller that contains text fields. However, the text fields aren't shown properly. It seems like they need a margin from top. As shown in this screenshot

[image]

Here is my code

First controller

```
    class OneController < UITableViewController
     ....
       def viewDidLoad
        super

        rmq.stylesheet = OneControllerStylesheet

        view.tap do |table|
          table.delegate = self
          table.dataSource = self
          rmq(table).apply_style :table
        end

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem.alloc.initWithBarButtonSystemItem(
            UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd,
            target: self,
            action: :addSomething)]
      end

  def addSomething
    self.add_category_controller.player = nil

    ctlr = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(self.add_something_controller)
    ctlr.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
    ctlr.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(ctlr, animated:true, completion:nil)
  end

  def add_something_controller
    @add_something_controller ||= TwoController.new.tap do |ctlr|
        ctlr.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.initWithBarButtonSystemItem(
            UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel,
            target: self,
            action: :cancelAdd)

        ctlr.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.initWithBarButtonSystemItem(
            UIBarButtonSystemItemDone,
            target: self,
            action: :doneAdd)

        ctlr.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = false
    end
  end

    ...
    end
```

Second controller

```
    class TwoCategoryController < UIViewController
      ...
      def viewDidLoad
        puts "viewDidLoad"

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor

        self.view.addSubview(self.first_field)
        self.view.addSubview(self.last_field)
      end
     ...
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 6 (and prior), your view would have had its origin set to {x: 0, y: 64} (in window coordinates), which is below the navigation bar.

In iOS 7, though, we now have "full screen" views almost *all* the time.  So that's what you're bumping into here.  Your view is at {x: 0, y: 0}, and so is below the navigation and status bar.

I think the correct way to fix this is to use constraints on your controller view (`self.view` in `TwoCategoryController`), and you can use the `UIViewController#topLayoutGuide` and `#bottomLayoutGuide` to position it *inside* the visible area.

That would be the "correct" way, but you can also make it easy on yourself and just find out the height of the nav bar (44) + status bar (20), and store that in a variable or method, and then just correct the text field frames to be offset below that.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller needs to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to NO.

The iOS 7 default is that scroll views fill the whole screen, include "under" the status and navigation bars.

Alternatively, you could make the nav and status bars translucent and just add padding above your text views.

Comment: I don't think he's using a scroll view in the `TwoCategoryController`, so `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` will have no effect here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a rubymotion developer but found [this](http://blog.motioninmotion.tv/fixing-the-ios-7-navigation-bar-overlap-problem) answer. Hope it will help :)